# deep copy of object which hold references to other objects

Tags: c++, reference, smart-pointers, deep-copy

I have a "sum" class which holds two references to existing ints (say). I want to create a "copy" method which deep copies the ints. I thought I would never have to manually `delete` objects in my code, thanks to smart pointers, but I had to in this solution. Moreover, it is too complicated for a so trivial task (which I need to repeat for several classes). Is there a more straightforward solution?

Note: I don't want to add a bool member (flag) to each objects to determine if the ints must be deleted (in my case, it's not a better overhead than the `std::set` check overhead in the destructor)

```
#include <set>

struct sum {
   const int &a, &b;
   static std::set<const int*> allocated_ints;

   sum(const int& a, const int&b): a(a), b(b) {}

   sum copy() const {
       sum res(*new const int(a), *new const int(b));
       allocated_ints.insert(&res.a);
       allocated_ints.insert(&res.b);
       return res;
   }

   ~sum() {
       if (allocated_ints.count(&this->a)) {
           delete &this->a;
           delete &this->b;
           allocated_ints.erase(&this->a);
           allocated_ints.erase(&this->b);
       }
   }

};

std::set<const int*> sum::allocated_ints;
```

Comment: You should not be deleting these references.

Comment: @rafak: Your code takes references to `int`s, which means they are "owned" by some other class, and your class should not delete them.  If they aren't "owned" by some other class, then you should not be storing the `int`s by reference.

Comment: What smart pointers are you talking about? I don't see any smart pointers in your code. (References aren't smart pointers, if that's what you were thinking.)

Comment: @John: I put my use case as a comment of Kerrek SB's answer. I need to delete the reference when they are allocated from within the class.

Comment: @MooingDuck: int's are most often owned by other classes. In rare cases, they are not (that's why I need to construct them by copy).

Comment: @FredOverflow: I would hope to be able to do something like: sum copy() { return sum(*std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(a)), *std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(b))); }

Comment: @rafak: If they're unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr, just make them non-reference members.

Comment: @rafak: I don't understand why you need a deep copy. Why not a shallow copy of the references?  Are the `int`s not guaranteed to be in scope for the duration of the copy?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Ususally I don't need a deep copy, the class uses mostly a reference semantic. But it may happen I need to save the state of the object with a copy, while the original is changing.

Comment: Why are you using references instead of pointers?

Answer (score 2):

What's the point of a "deep" copy of *constants*? The constants are going to have the same value no matter what! So just copy (i.e. alias) the const-references:

```
struct Foo
{
  const int & n;

  Foo(const int & m) : n(m) { }
  Foo(const Foo & rhs) : n(rhs.n) { }

  Foo copy() const { Foo f(*this); /* ... */ return f; }
  // ...
};
```

If you're worried about dangling references when returning a copy from a function with a reference to a local variable, then don't make the class have const references, but copies. That way you naturally give your class the copy semantics that you seem to be after anyway.

If you were thinking that you could make a hybrid which is either non-owning or becomes owning depending on how you use it, then I'd say that's bad design that you should avoid. Decide whether your class has ownership over the data or not and then roll with it.

Comment: it is mostly a reference semantic. Here is my use case: int n=1; Foo foo(n); /* compute with foo, but manipulating n directly */; if (foo.is_intersting()) Foo good_foo = foo.copy(); /* go on computation with foo, changing the value of n... */ (so the const-ness of the reference is not very relevant to my problem). Note: "C" comments don't display well

Comment: Hm, somehow this looks like poor encapsulation to me. I'd either make `n` a parameter, lile `foo.compute(n);`, or I'd make the entire logic which modifies `n` part of the class. Then you can make a straight copy of the object once you've hit an interesting state.

Comment: That's a bad idea, for the case of `Foo func() {return Foo(1);}`.  This would return a `Foo` with a dangling reference, causing undefined behavior.  The class should make it's own local copy, unless you can guarantee the `int`s are in scope longer than `Foo`.  Also, they can't "change the value of n", since they keep the references as `const`.

Comment: ... otherwise this just really gets ugly. You're asking for a single variable to which other parts of your code hold references, but you also want to make archival copies of that variable. That's no good. Maybe better to make a container that allows for persistent references, like so: `list<int> nvals; nvals.push_back(1); while(computing) {  Foo current_foo(nvals.back()); if(good) { Foo good_foo(current_foo); nvals.push_back(nvals.back()); }` This isn't quite right, but you get the idea: maintain a list of values whose last one is the current one, and previous ones are the archive.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, as I was saying, the OP's strongly coupled design is awkward and causes these complications. I'm willing to bet that there's a better overall approach that makes all those problems go away.

Comment: I agree. I always can garrantee that the `int`s are in scope longer than foo. In fact, i'm client of this code from python, and Boost.Python takes care of that for me (thanks to constructor policies). In my case, the "int's" are (math) functions. So my "sum" is a kind of lazy (lightweight) function representing the sum. I use a python generator function which manipulates two functions, and yields the sum (yielding the sum of the copies is too heavy). The client of this generator wants to copy elements from this generator (the sum in this case) only when interesting, and go on.

Comment: @rafak: OK, another idea: Since you want your backup copies of the `Foo` objects to refer to backup copies of your integer, you could make the copy function take a reference: `void Foo::copy(const int & m) { Foo f(m); /* copy other stuff */ return f; }`.

Comment: @Kerrek: it is a good idea, but the higher level client knows nothing about the Foo (the sum in my case), it needs to generically call f.copy(), whatever f is.

Comment: @rafak: it's probably best if you post a complete, minimal example façade that reflects your precise requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing-up two incompatible concepts.

If you initialize by reference you should refer to existing object whose lifetime is already defined and should be longer than your objects.

If you want to create a copy of your object, since it *refers to* something, your copy will also refer to *that* something.

If you want to own yourself dynamic supplied objects, you should use pointers for that, and acquire them as pointers (and delete them on destruction). A copy can then deep-create copies of the pointed objects (or can share them using reference counting or shared_ptr).

You are -in fact- making up a mixing of the two things, resulting in possible problems: think to:

```
int main()
{
    const int x=5; //whatever it is
    Foo foo(x);
    // ...
} //danger here! ~Foo() will delete x
```

Answer (score 0):

The references are not deep copied, because they point to an object. Therefore, your code fixed should look like this :

```
struct sum {
   const int &a, &b;

   sum(const int& a, const int&b): a(a), b(b) {}

   sum copy() const {
       sum res(a,b);
       return res;
   }

   ~sum() {
   }

};
```

Comment: But I need the copy to have "references" to new objects. Your version of copy is like the default copy constructor.

Comment: @rafak In that case, change the references to pointers (better yet smart pointers), or remove the reference (make them the objects). The above is how the references are copied.